# Get HTML from Safari share extension?

Tags: ios, xcode, safari-extension, ios8-extension, ios8-share-extension

In the share extension, I managed to get the URL of the Safari page with the following code:

```
NSExtensionItem *item = self.extensionContext.inputItems.firstObject;
NSItemProvider *itemProvider = item.attachments.firstObject;
if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeURL]){
    [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeURL
                                    options:nil
                          completionHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error){
                              NSLog(@"%@", url.absoluteString);
                          }];
}
```

Can I get also the HTML of the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the following code,

```
[itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier: (NSString *) kUTTypePropertyList
                                options: 0
                      completionHandler: ^(id<NSSecureCoding> item, NSError *error) {
                          if (item != nil) {
                              NSDictionary *resultDict = (NSDictionary *) item;
                              NSString *jsString = resultDict[NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingResultsKey][@"content"];
                          }
                      }];
```

[Creating an iOS App Extension to perform custom actions with Safari content - swiftiostutorials.com](http://swiftiostutorials.com/tutorial-creating-ios-app-extension-ios-8-perform-custom-actions-safari-content/)

Comment: thank you for your answer but its not working... _Printing description of *(item):
(id) [0] = <parent is NULL>_  _Printing description of item:
<nil>_

Comment: Printing description of error:
Error Domain=NSItemProviderErrorDomain Code=6902136592 "No item available for requested type identifier." UserInfo=0x174269b80 {NSLocalizedDescription=No item available for requested type identifier.}

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check that tutorial

Comment: @benhi It may be missed key in info.plist NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount with nonzero value.